# Writing a script to copy a folder and contents based on the length of an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, copy, directory

I know almost nothing about bash but I know this is a fast way to do this.
My psudo code is in JS.  But any language will do e.g. node, python, bash.

**step 1:** I have an array:

`var langArr = ["af","am"];`

**step 2:** I have a folder.

[image]

### **Question:**

How would I copy this folder based on the `langArr.length` (2) times; Place those new copied folders 'languages' directory; name those directories from the `langArr` index values?

In the end we'll have 1 parent folder and 3 children

```
- languages
 -- copy-this
  --- copy-this.txt
 -- af
  --- copy-this.txt
 -- am
  --- copy-this.txt
```

Comment: Where do `af` and `am` actually come from? Do they have to be in an array?

Comment: They don't have to be in an array it just the best ay I can think to iterate through

Comment: I have a huge list of locale folders I have to generate.  They are just duplicated folder of the 'copy-this' folder

Comment: And what does that list look like? A text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this...

```
 $ dirs=(af am)
 $ for d in ${dirs[@]}
 > do
 > mkdir languages/$d
 > cp languages/copy-this/copy-this.txt languages/$d
 > done
```